# Why the superfluous calls to filter functions when `std::views::reverse` is used?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to understand the sequence of calls to filter functions when passed through pipe operators (views/adapters). The result I see is not intuitive at all. While there might be reasons for it, I'd appreciate if someone can walk this through. As well if one can point to right documentation on [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const auto vec = std::vector{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    auto filter = [](const auto f) {
        std::cout << "f = " << f << ", "; 
        return f % 2 == 0;
    };

    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto v : vec
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::filter(filter)
        | std::views::take(2)
        | std::views::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "v = [" << v << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Actual result:**

```
f = 6, f = 5, f = 4, f = 3, f = 2, f = 3, f = 4, 
v = [4]
f = 3, f = 4, f = 5, f = 6, 
v = [6]
f = 5, f = 6,
```

**Expected result:**

```
f = 6, f = 5, f = 4, f = 3, f = 2, f = 1, 
v = [4]
v = [6]
```

Here is the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/adE88r) sample for code above. And here is [some more code](https://godbolt.org/z/4ThxGr), I tried to break it down to understand. But nothing strikes out as obvious.

Comment: Elements of `filter_view` are produced lazily. That is, the `filter` is called each time its iterator is incremented (or decremented). If that's not what you want, use the `remove_if` algorithm instead.

Comment: @cpplearner that still doesn't explain the behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range-based for loop in question can be rewritten to

```
auto&& range = vec
    | std::views::reverse
    | std::views::filter(filter)
    | std::views::take(2)
    | std::views::reverse;

auto begin = range.begin();
auto end = range.end();

for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    auto v = *begin;
    std::cout << std::endl << "v = [" << v << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

1. The initializer of `range` only builds the view. Nothing is outputted.
2. `range.begin()` returns a `reverse_iterator` whose `base()` is an iterator to the end of the underlying view. In order to find the end of the underlying view, 5 calls to `filter` are made (corresponding to `f = 6, f = 5, f = 4, f = 3, f = 2,` ).
3. `range.end()` returns a `reverse_iterator` whose `base()` is an iterator to the beginning of the underlying view. The beginning of `filter_view` has been cached. No call to `filter` is made.
4. `begin != end` returns true.
5. `*begin` decrements a copy of the underlying base iterator in order to access the first element of the reversed range. This results in the next 2 calls to `filter` (corresponding to `f = 3, f = 4,` ).
6. The value of the first element is outputted. (`v = [4]`)
7. `++begin` decrements the underlying base iterator. (`f = 3, f = 4,` )
8. `begin != end` returns true.
9. `*begin` decrements a copy of the underlying base iterator to access the second element. (`f = 5, f = 6,` )
10. The value of the second element is outputted. (`v = [6]`)
11. `++begin` decrements the underlying base iterator. (`f = 5, f = 6,` )
12. `begin != end` returns false.

Comment: This is _very_ disappointing to me.  The whole point of the range lib was to stop the annoyance of passing around _two_ things - the iterators to begin and end.  So the range library is supposed to handle containers as units.  So the first thing that happens here is that range::reverse is (supposedly) passed a vector - from which it can immediately get a size, and random access iterators and rend (!!) and what does it do but behave as if it has been handed only a _forward iterator_ to begin() and it traverses the vector increment by increment.  Really?  This is what we've been waiting for?

Comment: @davidbak The first reverse can do that. The second reverse can't, because `filter` gives you a forward range

Comment: The first call to `views::reverse` does preserves the size. But `views::filter` cannot know its size in advance, though it can (and does) return an iterator to its end (which is equal to the end of the reversed container). But then `views::take(2)` takes away that ability.

Comment: @Caleth `filter` can give you a bidirectional range if the underlying range is bidirectional (as it is in this case). Indeed, if `filter` didn't give you a bidirectional range, you couldn't reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of comments - the `std::views` objects are applied lazily on every iterator incrementattion. So doing something like this:

```
auto view = vec
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::filter(filter)
        | std::views::take(2)
        | std::views::reverse
```

effectivelly does not perform any computations on the range. Only when you iterate over the range the logic within the views is applied. This has some pros - no computations are made when no one uses the data. The drawbacks are like the one you mentioned - counterintuitive number and order of calls and often increased big O complexity.